# A Route Finding Android app

Tags: java, android

I've recently taken an interest in Android applications and I have been working on an app regarding the travelling salesman problem.
My app is a kind of a trip optimizer which is meant for travelers, so that they can optionally choose a starting point and a destination/multiple destinations. Right now the app works fine.

I want to reduce/shorten this class quite a lot. if you see that a method /methods can be reduced or even erased please do not hesitate to suggest that.
Any answer that rescue the class would be great :)

```
public class MSA extends NSA implements SRF.saveRouteDialogListener,
                OnMapReadyCallback, OnCameraChangeListener, OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback, OnStreetViewPanoramaChangeListener,
                ConnectionCallbacks, OnStreetViewPanoramaCameraChangeListener, StreetViewPanorama.OnStreetViewPanoramaClickListener,
                OnMapClickListener, OnPolylineClickListener, LocationListener, OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback,
                GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener, RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private GoogleMap m_routeMap;

    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private StreetViewPanorama streetViewPanorama;
    private SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment streetViewPanoramaFragment;

    private int nof = 0;
    private List<String> list;
    private Marker[] markers;
    private int markerIndex = 0;
    private String rN;

    private String mode = "driving";
    private MC objController = new MC();
    private LinkedList<List<LatLng>> listPolylines = new LinkedList<>();
    private LinkedList<Polyline> polyLines = new LinkedList<>();

    private SI m_objSearchInputs;

    private static final LatLng SYDNEY = new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689);

    int index = 0;
    private TextView textView;
    private boolean viewPolylineInfo = false;
    private int polyLineID = -1;

    Location myLocation = null;

    private float bearing = 0;
    private int currentPositionIndex = 0;
    private boolean playSubroute = false;
    private boolean reset = false;
    private int polyLineIdIndex = 0;
    private boolean playRoute = false;
    private boolean waypoint = false;
    private int SV_current_index = 0;
    private float bearingSV;
    private boolean bearingFinished = false;
    boolean showStreetView = false;

    boolean polyLinesDrawn = false;
    TextView currentLL;
    TextView currentB;
    TextView distanceTo;
    TextView bearingTo;
    Button beginRoute;
    boolean following = false;
    int bearingToPoint;
    int distanceToPoint;
    int polylineIndex = 0;
    int pointIndex = 0;
    LatLng currentLatLng;
    float currentBearing;

    CheckBox checkBox;
    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> markerIndexToPolylineIndex = new HashMap<>();
    boolean markerClicked = false;
    private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> subrouteMarked = new HashMap<>();
    private RadioGroup rgroup;
    private List<String> routeInfoTexts = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean clearRB = false;
    private LinearLayout navigationButtonBar;
    private Button showTextInfo;
    private Button showStreetViewButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_map_screen, mContentLayout);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null) {



            m_objSearchInputs = extras.getParcelable("user_search_inputs");
            list = m_objSearchInputs.m_DestinationList;
            markers = new Marker[list.size()];

            String commute = m_objSearchInputs.cM.toString();
            ImageButton button = null;
            if(commute.equals("WALK")) {
                button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnByWalk);
                mode = "walking";
            }

            else if(commute.equals("CAR")) {
                button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnByCar);
                mode = "driving";
            }

            objController.setMode(mode);
            if(button != null) {
                button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }

            System.out.println("Go back and forth: "+m_objSearchInputs.cM.toString());
        }
        setInputsForSearch();


        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.routeMapFragment);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        rgroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rgroup);
        rgroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        navigationButtonBar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.navigationButtonBar);

        beginRoute = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartNavigation);
        beginRoute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int size = polyLines.get(polyLineID).getPoints().size();
                LatLng latLng = polyLines.get(polyLineID).getPoints().get(size - 1);

                double lat = latLng.latitude;
                double lon = latLng.longitude;
                String m = null;

                    if (mode.equals("driving")) m = "h";

                    if (mode.equals("walking")) m = "p";
                    String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "google.navigation:q=%f,%f&mode=%s", lat, lon, m);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }


        });

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.polylineInfo);
        textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        showTextInfo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.routeInfoText);

        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(200);


        streetViewPanoramaFragment = (SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.streetviewFragment);
        streetViewPanoramaFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(
                new OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama panorama) {

                        streetViewPanorama = panorama;
                        streetViewPanorama.setOnStreetViewPanoramaChangeListener(MSA.this);
                        streetViewPanorama.setOnStreetViewPanoramaCameraChangeListener(MSA.this);
                        streetViewPanorama.setOnStreetViewPanoramaClickListener(MSA.this);

                        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

                            streetViewPanorama.setPosition(SYDNEY);
                        }
                    }
                });

        hideSV();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_map_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void displaySaveRouteDialog() {

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        SRF frag = new SRF();
        frag.show(fm, "fragment_save_route");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishInputDialog(String strRouteName) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        m_routeMap = googleMap;

        m_routeMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        m_routeMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        m_routeMap.setOnPolylineClickListener(this);
        m_routeMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(this);
        m_routeMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);
        m_routeMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            System.out.println("MY LOCATION ENABLED");
            m_routeMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


            List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
            for(String prv: providers) {
                System.out.println("| " + prv);
                myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(prv);
                if(myLocation != null) {
                    System.out.println("MYLOCATION: " + myLocation);
                    break;
                }
            }

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, this);
        }

        int i = 0;
        for(String location: list) {

            List<Address> addresses = null;
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
            try{
                if(location.equals("CURRENT_LOCATION")) {

                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude(), 1);
                    String lat = myLocation.getLatitude()+"";
                    String lon = myLocation.getLongitude()+"";
                    list.set(i, new String(lat + "," + lon));
                } else {
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
                }
            } catch (IOException ioe) {

                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(addresses != null) {

                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                markers[i++] = m_routeMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(location));
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Current Location is : " + myLocation);

        startCalculateThread();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLoaded() {

        onProceed();
        showAllPolyLines();
        loadRadioButtons();
    }

    private void loadRadioButtons() {

        for(String routeInfo: routeInfoTexts) {
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
            rb.setText(routeInfo);
            rgroup.addView(rb);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama panorama) {

        long duration = 20;
        float tilt = 30;
        float bearing = 90;

        StreetViewPanoramaCamera camera = new StreetViewPanoramaCamera.Builder()
                .zoom(panorama.getPanoramaCamera().zoom)
                .bearing(bearing)
                .tilt(tilt)
                .build();

        panorama.setPosition(new LatLng(52.208818, 0.090587));
        panorama.setStreetNamesEnabled(false);
        panorama.setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
        panorama.animateTo(camera, duration);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

        if(viewPolylineInfo) {

            viewPolylineInfo = false;
        }

        for(Polyline p: polyLines) {

            p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            p.setVisible(true);
        }

        if(markerClicked) markerClicked = false;

        clearRB = true;

        navigationButtonBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        rgroup.clearCheck();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {


        int id = Integer.parseInt(polyline.getId().substring(2,3));
        String[] html_instructions = objController.getHTML(id);

        System.out.println("\nROUTE INSTRUCTION: ");
        String message = "";
        for(String html_route: html_instructions){
            html_route = html_route.replaceAll( "<[^>]*>", "" );
            System.out.println(html_route);
            message += "-" + html_route + "\n";
        }

        System.out.println("\n");
        if(viewPolylineInfo) {

            if(id != polyLineID) {

                for(Polyline p: polyLines) {
                    p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
                polyline.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                textView.setText(message);
            } else {

                for(Polyline p: polyLines) {
                    p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                }

                viewPolylineInfo = false;
                textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                beginRoute.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                checkBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
        } else {

            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textView.setText(message);
            polyline.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            viewPolylineInfo = true;
            if(id == 0 || (id > 0 && subrouteMarked.get(id-1))) {
                beginRoute.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                checkBox.performClick();
                checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }

        polyLineID = id;
    }

    public void viewPolylineInfo(View view){

        Button b = (Button) view;


        if(viewPolylineInfo) {

            viewPolylineInfo = false;
            b.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            viewPolylineInfo = false;
            textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {

            viewPolylineInfo = true;
            String[] html_instructions = objController.getHTML(polyLineID);

            System.out.println("\nROUTE INSTRUCTION: ");
            String message = "";
            for(String html_route: html_instructions){
                html_route = html_route.replaceAll( "<[^>]*>", "" );
                System.out.println(html_route);
                message+="-"+html_route+"\n";
            }

            System.out.println("\n");
            b.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textView.setText(message);


        }

    }


    public void onShowStreetView(View view) {

        if(showStreetView){
            showStreetView = false;
            hideSV();
        }
        else{
            showStreetView = true;
            showSV();
        }
    }

    private void showSV() {

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
                .show(streetViewPanoramaFragment)
                .commit();
    }

    private void hideSV() {

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
                .hide(streetViewPanoramaFragment)
                .commit();
    }


    public void onPlayRoute(View view) {

        polyLineID = polyLineIdIndex;
        Button button = (Button)view;

        if(playRoute){

            button.setText(">>");
            playRoute = false;
            reset = true;

        } else {

            streetViewPanorama.setPosition(polyLines.get(0).getPoints().get(0));
            button.setText("||");
            playRoute = true;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }

            animateRoute();

        }
    }




    private void animateRoute() {


    }

    private void animateStreetView() {

        long duration = 500;
        float tilt = 0;

        LatLng from = polyLines.get(0).getPoints().get(SV_current_index);
        LatLng to = polyLines.get(0).getPoints().get(SV_current_index+1);


        StreetViewPanoramaCamera streetViewPanoramaCamera = new StreetViewPanoramaCamera.Builder()
                                                                    .zoom(streetViewPanorama.getPanoramaCamera().zoom)
                                                                    .bearing(bearingSV)
                                                                    .tilt(tilt)
                                                                    .build();

        streetViewPanorama.animateTo(streetViewPanoramaCamera, duration);
        streetViewPanorama.setPosition(to);


    }

    private void zoomOut(LatLng target) {

        CameraPosition cP = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                            .target(target)
                                            .zoom(17)                  
                                            .bearing(90)             
                                            .tilt(30)                  
                                            .build();               
        currentPositionIndex = 0;
        m_routeMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cP));
    }


    private void showAllMarkers() {

        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        for(Marker marker: markers) {
            builder.include(marker.getPosition());
        }
        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50);

        m_routeMap.animateCamera(cu);
    }


    private void showAllPolyLines() {

        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        for(Polyline polyline: polyLines) {

            List<LatLng> latLngs = polyline.getPoints();
            for(LatLng latLng: latLngs) {

                builder.include(latLng);
            }
        }

        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 170);
        m_routeMap.animateCamera(cu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cP) {


        if(playSubroute || playRoute) {
            if(waypoint) {
                waypoint = false;
                polyLineID++;

                if(polyLineID == polyLines.size()) {
                    playRoute = false;



                    polyLineID = 0;
                    showAllMarkers();
                }
                else
                    animateRoute();
            }
            else
                animateRoute();
        }
        else{
            if(reset) {
                reset = false;
                zoomOut(cP.target);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onStreetViewPanoramaChange(StreetViewPanoramaLocation streetViewPanoramaLocation) {


        if(SV_current_index < 10 && playRoute) {

            SV_current_index++;
            System.out.println(SV_current_index);
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie){
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }

            animateStreetView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStreetViewPanoramaClick(StreetViewPanoramaOrientation orientation) {

        Point point = streetViewPanorama.orientationToPoint(orientation);
        System.out.println("CLICK: " + point.toString());

        streetViewPanorama.animateTo(
                new StreetViewPanoramaCamera.Builder()
                        .orientation(orientation)
                        .zoom(streetViewPanorama.getPanoramaCamera().zoom)
                        .build(), 1000);
    }


    @Override
    public void onStreetViewPanoramaCameraChange(StreetViewPanoramaCamera streetViewPanoramaCamera) {

        System.out.println("CAMERA CHANGE: "+streetViewPanoramaCamera.bearing);
        if((int)(360 + bearingSV) == (int)streetViewPanoramaCamera.bearing && !bearingFinished) {
            bearingFinished = true;
            animateStreetView();
        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        currentLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        currentBearing = location.getBearing();
        currentLL.setText("Current LatLng: "+currentLatLng.latitude+","+currentLatLng.longitude);
        currentB.setText("Current Bearing: "+(int)currentBearing);
        if(myLocation == null) {
            System.out.println("FIRST TIME CHANGED");
        }

        System.out.println("LOCATION CHANGED: " + location.toString());

        if(polyLinesDrawn) {
            LatLng latLng = polyLines.get(polylineIndex).getPoints().get(pointIndex);
            float[] result = new float[3];
            Location.distanceBetween(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, result);
            if(result.length > 0){
                distanceToPoint = (int)result[0];
                if(result.length > 1){
                    bearingToPoint = (result[1] < 0) ? (int)(360 + result[1]) : (int)result[1];
                    bearingTo.setText("Bearing: "+bearingToPoint);
                }
                distanceTo.setText("Distance: "+distanceToPoint+" m");
            }
        }

        if(following) {

            CameraPosition cP = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(currentLatLng)      
                    .zoom(19)                   
                    .bearing(bearing)              
                    .tilt(67)                   
                    .build();                  

            m_routeMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cP));

            if(distanceToPoint < 5) {
                pointIndex++;
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        System.out.println("STATUS CHANGED");
    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        System.out.println("PROVIDER " + provider + " ENABLED");
    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        System.out.println("PROVIDER " + provider + " DISABLED");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        if ( ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

        if(!markerClicked) {

            int id = 0;
            System.out.println(marker.getId());
            System.out.println(marker.getTitle());
            for (int i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

                if (markers[i].getId().equals(marker.getId())) {
                    id = i;
                }
            }

            int polyLineIndex = markerIndexToPolylineIndex.get(id);
            for (int i = 0; i < polyLines.size(); i++) {

                if (i != polyLineIndex) {
                    polyLines.get(i).setVisible(false);
                    polyLines.get(i).setClickable(false);
                }
            }

            markerClicked = true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {


        if(clearRB){
            if(checkedId == -1){
                clearRB = false;
            }
        }
        else{

            navigationButtonBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(checkedId != -1){
                polyLineID = checkedId - 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < polyLines.size(); i++) {
                    if (i != polyLineID) {

                        polyLines.get(i).setVisible(false);
                        polyLines.get(i).setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    } else {
                        polyLines.get(i).setColor(Color.BLUE);
                        polyLines.get(i).setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            }
            showAllMarkers();
        }
    }


    private class calculateThread extends Thread {

        public calculateThread(){}

        @Override
        public void run(){

            int count = 0;
            routeInfoTexts.clear();
            int[][] optimizedRoute = objController.calculateTimeResult();
            for(String s: list){

                System.out.println("LIST: "+s);
            }

            for(int[] partRoute: optimizedRoute) {

                int fromIndex = partRoute[0];
                int toIndex = partRoute[1];
                if(fromIndex == toIndex) {
                    break;
                }

                markerIndexToPolylineIndex.put(toIndex, count);
                subrouteMarked.put(count, false);
                System.out.println("F: "+fromIndex + "  T: "+toIndex);

                String origin = list.get(fromIndex);
                String destination = list.get(toIndex);
                System.out.println(origin+" -> "+destination);

                objController.setDirectionOrigin(origin);
                objController.setDirectionDestination(destination);

                String polyLine = objController.fetchPolyLine();
                if(polyLine.equals("NO ROUTE")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mode not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    System.out.println("ERROR: "+ polyLine);
                    count++;
                    if(count == nof){
                        break;
                    }

                    continue;
                }

                List<LatLng> listPolyLine = objController.decodePoly(polyLine);
                listPolylines.addLast(listPolyLine);

                count++;
                if(count == nof){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void setInputsForSearch() {

        objController.setListMatrix(list);
    }

    private void onProceed() {

        index = 0;
        markerIndex = 0;
        int colorValue;
        int width;

        colorValue = Color.YELLOW;
        width = 20;

        System.out.println("SIZE: " + listPolylines.size());
        for(int i = 0; i < listPolylines.size(); i++) {
            Polyline p = m_routeMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(listPolylines.get(i)).width(22).color(Color.parseColor("#aab1ff")).geodesic(true).clickable(true));
            polyLines.add(p);
        }

        polyLinesDrawn = true;


    }

    private void clearPolyLines() {

        for(Polyline p: polyLines){
            p.remove();
        }

        polyLines.clear();
        listPolylines.clear();
    }

    private void startCalculateThread() {


        Thread thread = new calculateThread();
        thread.start();


        try{
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void traceRouteByMode(View v) {

        clearPolyLines();


        ImageButton b1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnByWalk);

        ImageButton b2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnByCar);

        b1.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getBaseContext(), R.color.primary));
        b2.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getBaseContext(), R.color.primary));


        ImageButton button = (ImageButton) v;
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

        if(v.getId() == R.id.btnByWalk) {
            mode = "walking";



        } else if(v.getId() == R.id.btnByCar) {
            mode = "driving";

        } 

        objController.setMode(mode);
        markerIndexToPolylineIndex.clear();

        startCalculateThread();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < routeInfoTexts.size(); i++){
            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)rgroup.getChildAt(i);
            radioButton.setText(routeInfoTexts.get(i));
        }
        rgroup.clearCheck();

        onProceed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this question has already been reviewed, please do not make changes to the code in the question as this invalidates answers.  If you have questions, feel free to explore our meta site or ask in our chat room.

Comment: In particular, please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to review everything in detail, so I'll take a few things and maybe someone else will look at others.

#### Whitespace

> ```
>                 String m = null;
>
>                     if (mode.equals("driving")) m = "h";
> ```

Looks like a mixture of tabs and spaces. It's better to be consistent and stick to one or the other, because otherwise changing tabstop (StackExchange automatically turns tabs into spaces with a tabstop of 4) makes the code hard to read.

> ```
>         if(extras != null) {
>
>
>
>             m_objSearchInputs = extras.getParcelable("user_search_inputs");
> ```

I don't think those three blank lines serve any useful purpose, but the excess of blank lines means that fewer important lines fit on screen. Obviously some of this is personal preference, but I think there are at least 133 blank lines which would be better removed.

---

#### Naming

> ```
> public class MSA extends NSA implements SRF.saveRouteDialogListener
> ```

MSA? NSA? SRF? If you want to obfuscate the code, try putting Proguard or a similar tool into the compilation chain rather than obfuscating the original source...

Also, Java conventions (which I think Android follows) are that class names should start with an upper case letter, so it should be `SaveRouteDialogListener` (and there are some other classes which also don't follow the convention and should be fixed).

> ```
>     public void onShowStreetView(View view) {
>
>         if(showStreetView){
>             showStreetView = false;
>             hideSV();
>         }
>         else{
>             showStreetView = true;
>             showSV();
>         }
>     }
> ```

Show me the method without a name and ask what it should be called, and I would say `toggleStreetView()`. The name `onShowStreetView` implies that this is called in response to the street view being shown, so it makes no sense that it should itself hide or show the street view. I suspect that it's actually an autogenerated name for a button or checkbox called `showStreetView`, but autogenerated names are not always useful names.

---

#### Debug code in production

> ```
>     @Override
>     public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
>
>         System.out.println("STATUS CHANGED");
>     }
>
>
>     @Override
>     public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
>
>         System.out.println("PROVIDER " + provider + " ENABLED");
>     }
>
>
>     @Override
>     public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
>
>         System.out.println("PROVIDER " + provider + " DISABLED");
>     }
> ```

Where does that output (and many other `System.out.println`s plus the odd `printStackTrace`) even go when you don't have a debugger attached? Either remove it completely or replace it with a proper logger, even if that's only `android.util.Log`.

---

#### No-ops

> ```
>     public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
>         if(viewPolylineInfo) {
>             viewPolylineInfo = false;
>         }
> ```

If `viewPolylineInfo` is initially `true`, this sets it to `false`. Otherwise, it leaves it as `false`. It is equivalent to writing

```
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        viewPolylineInfo = false;
```

which is not only shorter but requires marginally less thought to understand.

---

#### Threading

> ```
>     private class calculateThread extends Thread {
> ```

This has been discouraged for at least 10 years. Instead of extending `Thread` you should implement `Runnable`.

> ```
>     private void startCalculateThread() {
>         Thread thread = new calculateThread();
>         thread.start();
>
>         try{
>             thread.join();
>         } catch (InterruptedException ie){
>             ie.printStackTrace();
>         }
>     }
> ```

I'm not entirely sure whether there's something subtle going on here which needs a comment, or whether you've misunderstood the meaning of `Thread.join()`. This method doesn't just start the thread: it waits for it to stop. It might as well ditch the thread and do the calculation directly.

> ```
>             try {
>                 Thread.sleep(1000);
>             } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
>                 ie.printStackTrace();
>             }
> ```

This crops up a couple of times. Why? Freezing the UI thread for a second is a really bad idea.

---

#### God class

> ```
> public class MSA extends NSA implements SRF.saveRouteDialogListener,
>                 OnMapReadyCallback, OnCameraChangeListener, OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback, OnStreetViewPanoramaChangeListener,
>                 ConnectionCallbacks, OnStreetViewPanoramaCameraChangeListener, StreetViewPanorama.OnStreetViewPanoramaClickListener,
>                 OnMapClickListener, OnPolylineClickListener, LocationListener, OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback,
>                 GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener, RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {
> ```

Favour composition over inheritance. You don't necessarily need 15 classes to implement the 15 interfaces, but if you split them into logical groups and have one class per group it should make it easier to understand the overall structure, and given the number of empty `@Override` methods I wouldn't be entirely surprised if one or two of the interfaces turn out to be unnecessary.